# 지 in 제안하는지를 공부할 거예요

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

이렇게 오늘은 다른 사람에게 어떻게 제안하는지를 공부할 거예요 = Just like this, today will study proposing activities with other people

What is the meaning and grammar of 지를 here?

Link: https://youtu.be/zpsg4rV_uzU?t=53

Thanks.

Comment: not sure about the correctness of 를 here, but in general the bound noun 지 means "the uncertain fact whether (or not)" ...will study whether (or not) proposing...   Kind of seems like it should be 제안할(는)지 to me, which would mean "will study whether or not to propose" but anyways...

Comment: I agree that this sentence seems to be odd, but basically the idea is something like "study whether we should propose" or "study whether proposing.... is a good idea or not...."  something like that.  The speaker is implying that he's not sure about if this (proposing) is a good idea, basically...

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: I have just added the video.

Comment: @B.Alvn: if you notice I added the link right the time where the teacher said that sentence.

Comment: oh, I was just reading the text...my listening skills aren't up to your level, I guess...are you absolutely positive she said that exact sentence?

Comment: No, I have just studied Korean for more than 1 month and I also can not hear it. I used subtitle.

Comment: You know that those subtitles are typically automatically generated and often wrong, right?  No human is involved in most of those... just saying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

지 is noun of uncertainty, and is used to express a clause that is originally a question.

In your sentence,

> 이렇게 오늘은 다른 사람에게 어떻게 제안하는지를 공부할 거예요

The clause is 다른 사람에게 **어떻게** 제안하다, which is "how do we propose to others". In this case we will use the noun of uncertainty 지 since the clause is originally a question(i.e. there is a WH word 어떻게). So the sentence will mean:

> Today we will learn how to propose to others

Let me give other examples so as to let you understand more:

그 사람이 어딨는지 몰라요.

정확한 날짜가 언제인지에 따라 마련할 거예요.

There is actually one more use of 지: time. Example:

방에서 공부한 지 3시간이 지났다.

I have been studying in the room for 3 hours.

Check this link to understand more:

https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-2-lower-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-2-lessons-26-33/lesson-30/

Comment: Where is the uncertainty in "Today we will learn how to propose to others
" ?  Why is  지 used here, instead of perhaps 것?

Comment: @B.Alvn "how to propose to others" Since there is a WH word "how", the clause is a question, we use 지 instead of 것

Comment: How is that uncertain?  "how" just means "the method or way to do"...today we will learn how to turn on our computers.  today we will learn how to wash dishes.  no uncertainty in these expressions.....

Comment: Thanks. If possible, could you send a link so I can read more?

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Boy  what is the actual question here, in your opinion?  The word "how" is a often a kind of pronoun, isn't it?

Comment: Nice answer, although I'd make a few corrections: `그 사람이` **`어딨는지`** `몰라요`, `방` **`에서`** `공부한지 3시간이 지났다`. Personally I think `정확한 날짜가` **`언제인지에`** `따라` sounds a little awkward (sounds right, though) and would probably say `정확한 날짜에 맞춰서` instead (:

Comment: @B.Alvn The fact that you are asking a "how" question in this context shows that you are _uncertain_ about the methodology of the act at hand. If you wanted to use 것, you'd say 오늘은 다른 사람에게 제안하는 것을 배울거예요, although I'd say 법 sounds more suitable than 것 since "how" implies a "method" not an "object".

Comment: @spicypumpkin  thanks.  i like 법 too, but you know that 것 means a lot more than just "object" right?  it can mean any of:  thing, fact, phenomena, act, state, case, presumption, (the) one (that does/is~) ...and proposing is an act...짓 would work too, wouldn't it?

Comment: @spicypumpkin  So how different would this statement be to have the meaning I originally thought (above)...e.g. ...study whether or not proposing...  Would it only mean that if there was no question-type of pronoun involved (if we took out 어떻게 in this case) ?

Comment: @B.Alvn Yeah, sorry by "object" I meant "nouns in general," aka something that can be represented with "what". 짓 is often derogatory so I wouldn't recommend it. For our example, without the "how" the best would be to use 법 100%.

Comment: @spicypumpkin  Well, I think you've lost me now.  Anyways, have a nice day...lol

Answer (score 2):

> 지 depending noun : usage in time

그를 만난지도 오래 되었다.

Many time is passed after I met him

> 지 ending : intimate conversation

(1) 밥은 회사에서 먹고 오겠지

He may return after he eat at company.

(2) In intimate conversation, it can be used in question :

지훈이는 어디 갔지 ?

Where is Jihoon ?

(3) When we know the situation almost, it is used in confirming or
checking :

밖은 춥지 ? Is it cold outside, isn't it ?

(4) Suggestion :

그만 일어나지. Well, wake up.

(5) provocation :

자신있으면 니가 해봐

Do it if you are confident.

> **지 connecting :**

(1) 쓰레기를 버리지 마시요 (=버리는 것을 하지 마시요)

Stop your throwing waste.

더 이상 먹지 못하겠어요 (=먹는 것을 못하겠어요)

I can not eat more.

(2) and thus (=so that), hence :

무엇부터 해야 할지 시간만 보냈어

I do not know my work so that I spend a time

내일 얼마나 추울지 바람이 매섭게 부네

It is much windy so that how cold it is tomorrow ?

요커트와 요쿠르트 중 무엇으로 겨울을 준비할지 골라 보세요.

Choose yogurt or yoghurt so that you would prepare winter.

(3) Two facts in comparing sides :

고래는 짐승이지 물고기가 아니다.

Whale is animal but not fish.